# Create new columns with running count based on categorical column value counts in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

Suppose a given dataframe:

| Model | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Car | Red |
| Car | Red |
| Car | Blue |
| Truck | Red |
| Truck | Blue |
| Truck | Yellow |
| SUV | Blue |
| SUV | Blue |
| Car | Blue |
| Car | Yellow |

I want to add color columns that keep a count of each color across each model to give the following dataframe:

| Model | Color | Red | Blue | Yellow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Red | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Car | Red | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Car | Blue | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Truck | Red | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Truck | Blue | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Truck | Yellow | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| SUV | Blue | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| SUV | Blue | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Car | Blue | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Car | Yellow | 2 | 2 | 1 |

This dataset has billions of records so I'm trying to stay away from UDF's and prefer to use built in methods if possible.

I normally use a window function with .size() and .collect_set() to count this type of data but adding multiple different new df columns based of different column categories is causing me issues because I'm not sure if I need to isolate the individual categories by adding additional window partitions or a .where() or isin() method with one window partition. Any feedback or recommendations are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do that with `window` functions and built-in `PySpark` `DataFrame` functions, `window` can be quite expensive computationally, especially with large data sets so maybe search a better way for your method. Dont forget to replace `data` and `df` with your actual `data` and `DataFrame`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum as _sum

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [("Car","Red"), ("Car","Red"), ("Car","Blue"), ("Truck","Red"), 
        ("Truck","Blue"), ("Truck","Yellow"), ("SUV","Blue"), 
        ("SUV","Blue"), ("Car","Blue"), ("Car","Yellow")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Model", "Color"])

window_model = Window.partitionBy('Model')

df = df.withColumn('Red', _sum((col('Color') == 'Red').cast('int')).over(window_model))
df = df.withColumn('Blue', _sum((col('Color') == 'Blue').cast('int')).over(window_model))
df = df.withColumn('Yellow', _sum((col('Color') == 'Yellow').cast('int')).over(window_model))

df.show()
```

Comment: This working perfectly, I had tried a similar solution but what I was missing was casting as an integer. Thank you very much!

Comment: You welcome :)) dont forget to validate the answer if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about preserving the original order, it can be done as a one-liner:

```py
data = [("Car","Red"), ("Car","Red"), ("Car","Blue"), ("Truck","Red"), 
        ("Truck","Blue"), ("Truck","Yellow"), ("SUV","Blue"), 
        ("SUV","Blue"), ("Car","Blue"), ("Car","Yellow")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Model", "Color"])

df.join(df.groupBy("Model").pivot("Color").count().fillna(0), on='Model').show()

# +-----+------+----+---+------+
# |Model| Color|Blue|Red|Yellow|
# +-----+------+----+---+------+
# |  SUV|  Blue|   2|  0|     0|
# |  SUV|  Blue|   2|  0|     0|
# |  Car|   Red|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|   Red|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|  Blue|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|  Blue|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|Yellow|   2|  2|     1|
# |Truck|   Red|   1|  1|     1|
# |Truck|  Blue|   1|  1|     1|
# |Truck|Yellow|   1|  1|     1|
# +-----+------+----+---+------+
```

If you care about the order, it can still be done as a one-liner:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .join(df.groupBy("Model").pivot("Color").count().fillna(0), on='Model')\
    .orderBy("_id").drop("_id").show()

# +-----+------+----+---+------+
# |Model| Color|Blue|Red|Yellow|
# +-----+------+----+---+------+
# |  Car|   Red|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|   Red|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|  Blue|   2|  2|     1|
# |Truck|   Red|   1|  1|     1|
# |Truck|  Blue|   1|  1|     1|
# |Truck|Yellow|   1|  1|     1|
# |  SUV|  Blue|   2|  0|     0|
# |  SUV|  Blue|   2|  0|     0|
# |  Car|  Blue|   2|  2|     1|
# |  Car|Yellow|   2|  2|     1|
# +-----+------+----+---+------+
```